# Detect if message is intended to continue a conversation or start a new one

Tags: nlp

This is more of an understanding question than a code one.

I'd like to be able to detect if a message is a continuation of a conversation or an attempt to start a new one (switch intent).

Example where intent should be implied from previous question:

```
Q. How far away is the nearest Tesco?
A. 1 mile
Q. What about Sainsbury's?
```

Example where intent should be reclassified:

```
Q. How far away is the nearest Tesco?
A. 1 mile
Q. What is the weather going to be like tomorrow?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem falls under dialogue act classification. In the end I used the  https://github.com/cgpotts/swda and trained a classifier to do this.

:)